# Proper way of deleting records with Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I came across another Stackoverflow post regarding Get vs Post and it made me think.  With CI, my URL for deleting a record is http://domain.com/item/delete/100, which deletes record id 100 from my DB.  The record_id is pulled via `$this->uri->segment`.  In my model I do have a where clause that checks that the user is indeed the owner of that record.  A user_id is stored in a session inside the DB.  Is that good enough?

My understanding is, POST should be used for one time modification for data and GET is for retrieving regards (e.g. viewing an item or permalink).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really ought to require a post request when deleting.  In CodeIgniter this could be as simple as checking $this->input->post('confirm')

Part of the justification is you don't want data changed on a get request. Since you said you are requiring the person be the owner, there still is the problem that some one puts an image with the source being http://domain.com/item/delete/100  Using post isn't a cure-all as you can do post requests from javascript so it would still be possible for a malicious user to create the delete request if you aren't properly filtering input.

I should admit that I'm a bit of a purist and just feel requiring post is the right way.  Its how the standards were written (okay you could argue it should be a DELETE request but browsers typically don't support them) and in other cases you really need to use them (there have been cases of web crawlers deleting pages).

If you want to have the delete link be http://domain.com/item/delete/100 then you could display a confirmation message with a form that does a post action as confirming the deletion.

I hope this helps,
Bill

Comment: Yea, I wasn't sure how to go about deleting a record via a post request.  Any examples you can show? I assume all this should be in the model somewhere.  In my controller I pass the URI and session id to the model. The model checks these two values and deletes if they match.

Comment: You could just have a form submit to "item/delete" with $_POST['post_id'], $_POST['user_id'] (from hidden field).  the "delete" function in your "item" controller pulls the "$this->input->post('post_id')" and ->post('user_id') to verify permission and delete the record.

Comment: So if the user can delete a record via a link, do I pass"$this->uri->segment" to a $_POST variable?

Comment: Nevermind, I get it. I have to stop depending on "$this->uri->segment"